# How to specify exact size of spiral for printing

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I would like  to draw Archimedes spiral https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral with inter loop gap of 6mm and total diameter 30mm.  This is the size it should have when I print it.  My MWE (from Rosetta Stone) is:

```
from turtle import *
from math import *
color("blue")
down()
for i in range(200):
    t = i / 20 * pi
    x = (1 + 5 * t) * cos(t)
    y = (1 + 5 * t) * sin(t)
    goto(x, y)
up()
done()
```

How do I set the exact size?

Comment: What units do you think Python turtle graphics uses. Knowing this would be crucial to determining how be something would print. How are you printing the output anyway?

Comment: Print a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this isn't actually anything about the code, it's just the math to make it work out nicely.

The constant out front (`1 + 5*t` in your code) corresponds to how far out it moves every radian, so to increase by `6mm` every `2*pi` radians you would set that constant to `6/(2*pi) * t` so it'd look something like:

```
r = (6/(2*pi) * t)
x = r * cos(t)
y = r * sin(t)
```

the part that makes this have diameter 30 is what comes out for `r` for that the last value of `i`

```
i = 199
t = i/20 * pi # just under 10*pi
r = (6/(2*pi) * t) # 10pi/2pi = 5, 5*6 = 30 mm :)
```